# Importar .sql do PostgreSQL no Neo4j

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, grafo, neo4j

Tenho um arquivo de backup .sql do PostgreSQL e quero importar esse arquivo para o Neo4j (banco de dados em grafo). Como faço?

Answer (score 2):

O @BrunoRB está correto, você vai precisar em algum momento criar uma função de mapeamento `Modelo Relacional <--> Grafo` dos seus dados. [Este tutorial da Neo4j pode ajudá-la](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/).

Simplificando o link acima, você vai transformar cada registro de cada tabela do seu banco em um nó no grafo do Neo4j.

Dada a seguinte tabela:

```
                                Table "public.consumidor"
 Column |         Type          |                        Modifiers
--------+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer               | not null default nextval('consumidor_id_seq'::regclass)
 nome   | character varying(40) |
```

o que você precisa fazer é exportá-la para um arquivo `.csv` utilizando o comando `COPY` do PostgreSQL:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM consumidor) TO '/tmp/comsumidor.csv' WITH CSV header;
```

E criar os nós equivalentes no Neo4j utilizando o comando `LOAD CSV` da linguagem Cypher:

```
// Create customers
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:consumidor.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Consumidor {nome: row.nome, consumidorId: row.id});
```

Answer (score 1):

Não tem jeito fácil. Você vai ter que importar esse SQL para o postgresql, criar a sua estrutura equivalente no NEO4J e depois escrever um código de mapeamento dos dados que vai extrair eles do postgres e jogar nos campos equivalentes do NEO4J.